# Grouping multiple events in a single ics file (icalendar stream)

Tags: icalendar

I want to group multiple events in a single ICS file(iCalendar stream) according to the RFC. This can be done but I have no idea how. Can anyone help me or give me an example ?

Here is what rfc says:

> However, multiple iCalendar objects can be sequentially grouped
>   together in an iCalendar stream.  The first line and last line of the 
>   iCalendar object MUST contain a pair of iCalendar object delimiter
>   strings.  The syntax for an iCalendar stream is as follows:
>
> ```
>  icalstream = 1*icalobject
>
>  icalobject = "BEGIN" ":" "VCALENDAR" CRLF
>               icalbody
>               "END" ":" "VCALENDAR" CRLF
> ```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

here is a simple example of an icalendar file with two events.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//bobbin v0.1//NONSGML iCal Writer//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20100701T080000Z
DTEND:20100701T110000Z
DTSTAMP:20091130T213238Z
UID:1285935469767a7c7c1a9b3f0df8003a@yoursever.com
CREATED:20091130T213238Z
DESCRIPTION:Example event 1
LAST-MODIFIED:20091130T213238Z
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Example event 1
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20100701T120000Z
DTEND:20100701T130000Z
DTSTAMP:20091130T213238Z
UID:1285935469767a7c7c1a9b3f0df8003b@yoursever.com
CREATED:20091130T213238Z
DESCRIPTION:Example event 2
LAST-MODIFIED:20091130T213238Z
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Example event 2
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Copy this into a file and save it as events.ics and it should open in most icalendar compatible applications e.g. Outlook 2007, Sunbird, iCal. For more complicated examples you could try creating events in Google calendars and exporting the calendars to view the results or downloading preexisting calendars from somewhere like [icalshare.com](http://icalshare.com). The file format is similar to e-mail encoding in that it must be folded. Wikipedia has a pretty good article on ICalendar and if you Google "icalendar validator" you there are several services that will let you validate your files. Oh and if you get frustrated with it, you're not alone http://www.google.co.uk/support/forum/p/Calendar/thread?tid=366b19a87d1304ec&hl=en although it is a good spec imho, its implementations are very, er, different.

A little more detail on how you want to use it would help others help you.

Comment: This creates a new calendar in outlook, how the events in this (scripted) calendar can be merged into original calendar provided/used in outlook?

Comment: Thank you!  Exactly the sort of encouragement I was looking for.  I need to prepare an iCal file for a program with four events at irregular hours, a Friday evening, Saturday and Sunday morning and Wednesday evening.  I was hoping something like this might be possible!